# TCP Error code 10060 when client opening connection to WCF service in windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

I have a WCF service hosted in a Windows service on Window Server 2013.
Installed and got the service running fine and I can connect using Visual Studio.

When I run my app that is consurming the service I get the open timeout exception. I had a look around the web and I added the tracing as sugested here. [Self hosting wcf with nettcp exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467334/self-hosting-wcf-with-nettcp-exception)

Looking at the log genereated I see the detail on the error.

> Could not connect to net.tcp://ServerName:8001/MessagingService/service. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0691067. TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ServerIP:8001.

I am using net.tcp binding and I have opened ports 8000, 8001 both inbound and outbound for the service on the server. This changed nothing. I also set the rule for the service to allow any port and that made no difference.

Server Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>       
    <services>
        <service name="EMS.Messaging.Service.ChatService" behaviorConfiguration="MessagingServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="EMS.Messaging.Service.IChat" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http://ServerName:8000/MessagingService/service" />
                  <add baseAddress="net.tcp://ServerName:8001/MessagingService/service" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
     <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MessagingServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
              <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>           
    </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="tcpBinding" maxBufferSize="67108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864" transferMode="Buffered" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                       openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxConnections="100" portSharingEnabled="true">
        <security mode="None"/>
        <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxStringContentLength="67108864" />
        <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00" />
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="mexBinding">
        <tcpTransport maxPendingConnections="100">
          <connectionPoolSettings groupName="default" maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="100"/>
        </tcpTransport>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>       
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you try put something like:  `<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost: 8001/MessagingService/service" />` ?

Comment: Are you able to open it from the browser?

Comment: @Pabloker that actual config file has the correct base address, I just put in ServerName for posting here.
No I cannot access from browser, but then its not hosted in IIS so I image it wouldn't?

Comment: I know that. In some cases putting the server name doesn't work, and "localhost" does

Comment: @Pabloker puttig localhost cause's the clients config file to use localhost which means the client program will be trying to look locally for the service